# Is this Alloy model cheating?

Tags: alloy

Some Request for Comments (RFCs) have these two rules:

```
1. Each comma character must be escaped with a backslash.
2. A backslash that is not being used to escape a comma must be escaped with a backslash.
```

Here are valid values:

```
A\,B
A\\\,B
A\\\\\\\,B
```

Here are invalid values:

```
A\\,B
A,B
A\\\B
```

I created two Alloy models.

My second Alloy model has two signatures for backslashes:

```
sig Backslash extends Char {}
sig EscapedBackslash extends Char {}
```

The latter, of course, represents a double backslash. The former represents a single backslash.

Given those two signatures, it was really easy to express the rules:

```
Each comma must be preceded by a backslash. 
Each backslash must be followed by a comma.
```

I didn't need to worry about making sure certain backslashes were appropriately escaped. The `EscapedBackslash` signature already took care of that.

In my first model I had only one signature for backslash:

```
sig Backslash extends Char {}
```

It was very hard to implement the two rules. In fact, I never succeeded in implementing the rules.

As I stated earlier, the second model has this signature:

```
sig EscapedBackslash extends Char {}
```

which enabled me to completely avoid the task of checking that every backslash that is not being used to escape a comma is escaped. **Is that cheating?**

Here is my Alloy model (second model):

```
one sig Text {
    firstChar: Char
}

abstract sig Char {
    next: lone Char,
    prev: lone Char
} 

sig A extends Char {}
sig B extends Char {}
sig C extends Char {}
sig Comma extends Char {}
sig Backslash extends Char {}
sig EscapedBackslash extends Char {}

fact  Text_Structure {
    // If the i'th character is c and c.next is c', then c'.prev equals c
    all c: Char | some c.next => c.next.prev = c
    // The first character has no previous character
    no Text.firstChar.prev
    // No cycles in the forward direction, i.e., if the i'th character is c, then the 
    // i'th + n character cannot be c
    no c: Char | c in c.^next
    // No cycles in the backward direction, i.e., if the i'th character is c, then the 
    // i'th - n character cannot be c
    no c: Char | c in c.^prev
    // This is not necesssary. I just don't like to see miscellaneous relations.
    // This says that if a character is not in the string, then it has no next or previous character.
    all c: Char | c not in Text.firstChar.*next => no c.next and no c.prev
}

// Rule: Every comma MUST be escaped.
fact Every_Comma_Escaped {
    // The firstChar cannot be a comma
    Text.firstChar not in Comma
    all c: Text.firstChar.*next | c in Comma => c.prev in Backslash
}

// Rule: If a backslash is not being used to escape a character, 
// then the backslash MUST be escaped, i.e., the single backslash
// must occur only when preceding a comma.
fact Every_Literal_Backslash_Escaped {
     all c: Text.firstChar.*next | (c in Backslash) => (some c.next) and (c.next in Text.firstChar.*next) and (c.next in Comma)
}
```

Comment: You can't really cheat when you are the one making the rules.
The real question here is, why are you specifying this in Alloy? Find the answer to this question and you'll fortunately be able to judge if your model is relevant or not.

Comment: Hi @Loïc Gammaitoni. You invited me to reflect on what I am trying to specify in the Alloy model. Reflection is always a good thing, and I have done so. I simply want to model the escaping rules for commas and backslashes in RFCs. However, that doesn't answer my questions. I remain baffled on what is too much and too little abstraction. I remain baffled on whether it is cheating to simply ignore the problem with escaping literal backslashes.