# When is an Alloy model too abstract, when it is not abstract enough?

Tags: alloy

In [my last Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47190547/how-to-constrain-the-number-of-following-backslashes-to-an-odd-number-to-an-eve) I asked how to create an Alloy model that constrains every backslash to be escaped by another backslash, provided the backslash is not escaping a comma. Daniel Jackson replied to my post, suggesting that my model should be more abstract. In fact, I have created a more abstract model. But I felt that it was too abstract and it was avoiding the problem of constraining backslashes properly (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47168337/is-this-alloy-model-cheating)).

I am puzzled, when is an Alloy model too abstract, when it is not abstract enough?

Answer (score 0):

First, I think your model has an overly complex representation of the underlying world model. I recognize the problem you're trying to work in, escaping. And it sure is a nasty area.

Key for me would be to make the model use `seq` because it is a sequence of Char.

```
abstract sig Char {}
    abstract sig EscapedCharacter extends Char {}
one sig A,B,C extends Char {}
one sig Backslash, Comma extends EscapedCharacter {}

pred valid[ string : seq Char ] {
    string.isEmpty 
    or 
        string[0] = Backslash 
            implies {
              # string > 1 
          and string[1] in EscapedCharacter 
          and valid[ string.subseq[2,#string]]
                }
            else string[0] != Comma and valid[ string.rest ]    
}

run valid for 4
```

Unfortunately, this uses recursion. I actually fail how you could specify this without recursion but I am trying to find out. It is unfortunate, because you need to enable recursion in the menu and this is limited to 3 levels, which is imho to low for even small problems. The reason for this limit is that recursion needs to unrolled which explodes the state space. 
However, I hope we find a way to make recursion more of a first class citizen because the readability is quite high for most developers.

Anyway, it looks like it works when we assert some examples:

```
assert InvalidExample {
    not valid[ 0->Backslash ]
}
check InvalidExample for 4

assert InvalidExample2 {
    not valid[ (0->A) + (1->Backslash) + (2->Backslash)+  (3->Comma) ]
}
check InvalidExample2 for 4

assert ValidExample {
    valid[ (0->Backslash) + (1->Comma) ]
}
check ValidExample for 4
```

**Updated** missed in the original requirement Comma had to *always* be preceded by a Backslash (I applied my common sense instead of reading literally.)

Comment: Hi @Peter Kriens. I thought Alloy doesn't allow recursion? I don't think your solution prohibits this erroneous string: A\\,B

Comment: I assumed you did normal escaping in which \\, is ok. However, I now see that you always want a comma escaped (why??). then the change is not so hard. Just ensure in the else clause that string[0] is not a comma. I've updated the example. And yes, recursion is allowed up to 3 levels in options. I think we need to bump this. I also try to understand if this can be written differently because it is very clear imho